# Is there a special meaning to class names that start with a dollar sign ($)?

Tags: dart

Like in this example: https://github.com/brianegan/github_search_angular_flutter/blob/master/github_search_common/lib/src/ui/search_state.dart

The class is referenced to without the dollar sign in other parts of the code. I couldn't find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a valid character for any name in Dart. In this case, it looks like the convention for https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/meta_types

I'd look at that documentation.